# How to calculate percentage of sum column?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate percentage of my cumulative amount column i have following table

```
id  amount cumulative_amount
1   10000  10000
2   15000  25000
3    5000  30000
4   10000  40000
```

i want output as

```
id  amount cumulative_amount  percentage
1   10000  10000              100%
2   15000  25000              166.67% (i.e cumulative_amount*100/amount)
3    5000  30000              600%
4   10000  40000              400%
```

so how to write query in mysql to achieve above output

i have write below query

```
SELECT amount,SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS cumulative_amount,
concat(round((cumulative_amount/amount * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but i am getting mysql error stating that unknown column 'cumulative_amount' in field list so how i am gonna achieve my output
please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT amount,SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS cumulative_amount,
concat(round((SUM(amount) OVER(ORDER BY id))/amount * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```